# The server can not receive encrypted text by RSA in client/server application

Tags: c#, encryption

I am using RSA to encrypted text and then send the encrypted text to a server.  My problem is the server is unable to decrypt the text because the server can not read encrypted text correctly.
My code in the client is :

```
byte[] plaintext;
byte[] encryptedtext=new byte[128];
plaintext = ByteConverter.GetBytes("hello");
encryptedtext = Encryption(plaintext, RSAA.ExportParameters(false), false);
textBox10.Text = ByteConverter.GetString(encryptedtext);

byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox10.Text);
networkStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
```

my code in server :

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[handlerSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
dataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
byte[] encryptedtext=new byte[128] ;
//   dataReceived = ByteConverter.GetBytes(dataReceived);
encryptedtext = ByteConverter.GetBytes(dataReceived);
byte[] decryptedtex = Decryption(encryptedtext, RSA.ExportParameters(true), false);
if(decryptedtex!=null)
    textBox4.Text = ByteConverter.GetString(decryptedtex);
```

output :

In client, the encrypted text : 
`卅凉䂧즠淦燺◓㎜ზﾷ큺�㬧ᶥ숿둴ꖉ␽넵Տ懾쵌摘䙑원퀮歒�숈鬖姈㫑餓貜ǅ手葏㻐㺿⣨ꇑ橿朁繱�䘧殍㲙㦱䟽躮Ồᒛ鈉嫡짟`

but when the encrypted text is received by the server, it looks like:
`?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????`
and the server can not decrypt the text.

NOTE : the server has the correct information to decrypt the text (public key, private key ....)

So how I can solve this problem ?

Comment: How is the text sent to the server?  Is it WCF or is this a web app?  Is the client a web page or winforms or WCF?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just convert binary data to an ASCII string and hope that all the character encodings match up.  It just doesn't work like that.

Send the encrypted data as a `byte[]`. E.g.:

```
networkStream.Write(encryptedtext, 0, encryptedtext.Length);
```

You'll need to make the same change on the server side.

If you **really** want to send the data as a string (which I don't understand why you would want to), you can convert to base64 encoding instead of ASCII, which will be preserved properly:

```
string b64Str = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedtext);
```

Also, using `encryptedtext` as your variable name for a `byte[]` is super misleading.  You should change that.  You should also not be using RSA to send payloads and instead just send a symmetric key.  But if we were going to talk about that, you should really just be using TLS over an `SslStream`.